# Sleep for N seconds and wait for keypress

Tags: c, linux, nonblocking

I want to write a program in C that performs some function and then sleeps for some minutes.
During this sleep period I would like to do something and exit if a key is pressed.

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        /*body*/
        sleep(300);
    }
    /*some lines here*/
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway that I can exit the loop during either the sleep period or at any time using a non-blocking key listener?

Comment: Maybe you could use two threads, one for input and other one for processing. Unless its game loop, in that case I would prefer one thread for all tasks.

Comment: during sleep, the process/thread will go to in active queue, so no other operation can be performed until it resume.You have to use semaphore and two threads.

Comment: Read the time in seconds before you enter the loop. Then loop until the clock says it's 300 seconds later, or break out when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't sleep for 300 seconds but rather 300 x for 1 second and check for key press:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        /*body*/
        for ( int i=0; i<300; i++ )
        {
            if (keypressed())
                doSomething();
        }
    }
    /*some lines here*/
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Why the `while (1)` in your code? Do you really want to run your program endlessly? (In that case, `/*some lines here*/` doesn't make sense.)

Comment: i think the op wants to break the while loop if a key is pressed

Comment: @Axel :This will do well. Can you link something appropriate for the keypressed() funtion.

Answer (score 1):

there are several possible solutions:

1. use a timed select
2. use 2 threads - one waiting on the input and the other sleeping and doing the operation
3. As @Axel suggested, split the big sleep to several smaller sleep. To get an interval smaller than 1 sec, you can use usleep() or nanosleep()

The simplest solution would probably be 3, but is slightly less efficient, as it's using polling instead of event driven

Answer (score 0):

During this sleep period I would like to do something and exit if a key is pressed. - It is not possible.

Because during the sleeping period Process will go to suspend state. Once the process suspended, you cant do anything until it woke up again. In that sleeping time if you pressed any keys also your process won't come to know which what happened? or what key is pressed?. Because already Your process is suspended.

And in your code why you are using `while(1)`? -

```
while(1)
{
   /*body*/
   sleep(300);
}
/*some lines here*/ // Your program wont execute this part. Because you have while(1) before. It wont comes out of the loop.
```